# Python and Maya : Access to a variable in another function launched by a button

Tags: python, function, variables, button, maya

I have a simple python/pymel script in Maya that helps the user to copy the value of selected attributes in the channel box and paste them after the user would have selected another object and the same or other attributes.

There are 2 buttons, one to copy the attributes, one to paste them.
So first, the user selects the object with the attributes to copy from, and select those attributes in the channel box. Then he clicks on the first button : it launches a function that creates a list of the values of those selected attributes.
Then, he selects one or multiple objects, and the attributes in the channel box where he wants to paste what he copied. He clicks on the second button to paste those values.
Here comes my problem : I can’t find a way to access to the list I created with the first function.

Here is my code:

```
import pymel.core as pm
import pymel.core.windows as pw

#Here I define the functions getSelectedChannels(), copyAttrs(), and pasteAttrs()
#It works weel, unrelevant for my problem


#1, creates the list of values :
def copy_attr(*args):

    attrs = getSelectedChannels() #function to get the attributes names from the selection in the channel box
    attrsValues = copyAttrs(attrs)   #function to copy their values in the list attrsValues 
    return attrsValues               #at this point, my list is ok



#2, paste the values, but I can't access to the list
def paste_attrs(attrsValues,*args):

    attrs = getSelectedChannels()
    pasteAttrs(attrs,attrsValues)


#############################################################
#UI

#check if windows already exists
if pw.window(windowName, exists = True):
    pw.deleteUI(windowName)

#window creation & definition
myWindow = pw.window(windowName, t  = scriptName + " " + scriptVersion , w=100, h=100,)
pw.columnLayout(adj = True, columnAlign = "center")
pw.separator(h = 20)
pw.text(titleWindow)
pw.separator(h = 20)


pw.text("First, select the attributes you want")
pw.text("to copy from the channel box\n")
pw.text("Then, select the attributes in the channel  ")
pw.text("box where you wantto paste them\n")
pw.text("Finally, choose paste or reversed paste")
pw.separator(h = 20)

pw.gridLayout( numberOfColumns=3, cellWidthHeight=(110, 25) )

attrValues = pw.button(l = button_copy,width = 60, command = pm.Callback(copy_attr)) #attrValues doesn't correspond to the attrsValues list the function returned, that's where it fails
pw.button(l = button_paste,width = 60, command = pm.Callback(paste_attrs, attrValues )) 
pw.separator(h = 10)


pw.showWindow(myWindow)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you return the attribute value list, but you do not save it in any variable. As soon as the function returns, the data is lost. You need to find a way to keep the data between the function calls. You have two possibilities, a bad one an a better one. The bad one is to use global variables, in your case you would have to use:

```
def copy_attr(*args):
    global attrsValues
    attrs = getSelectedChannels()
    attrsValues = copyAttrs(attrs) 

def paste_attrs(*args):
    global attrsValues
    attrs = getSelectedChannels()
    pasteAttrs(attrs,attrsValues)
```

As mentioned this is a bad solution because global variables can cause trouble. A better solution would be to use a class and create the window within the class and define the functions as class methods. This way you can save the data in the class instace variables and do not have to use global variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I would like to use the class solution, but I've never used any, so it might be tricky... Is it complicated ?

Comment: Well... it depends a bit on how fast you learn ;) Have a look at how classes work and try it, if you have problems, we are here.